# Magento 2 : How to load payment methods in shipping step?

Tags: magento2.3, knockoutjs, checkout-page

I need to show payment methods in shipping step in Magento 2.3 checkout,
I have added done changes to file **checkout_index_index.xml**, and also I have added html code to **shipping.html file**.

But I still get **"No Payment Methods",** is there anything which I must add to **knockout.js** model to show payment methods before validating shipping step?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got the solution ?